# How to Upload Artifacts to Jfrog based on its Folder structure by using Jenkins Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I need to upload Artifacts to Jfrog based on its Artifact id and group id by using pipeline script. From Jenkins build there are hundreds of jar's and pom's needs to be uploaded.

Here the uploading location of every jar and pom will be based on its own artifact id, group id and its version.

Eg:

```
http://<artifactorylink>/<group id>/<artifac id>/<version>/<.jar>

http://<artifactorylink>/<group id>/<artifac id>/<version>/<.pom>
```

Am not familiar with Jenkins pipeline scripts, can anyone guide me on this to write a pipeline script that will upload artifacts based on its group id, version and artifact id mentioned in its own pom file!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the reported use case to pass the details in the pom.xml file, for example I have configured the pom.xml file as below:

```
<groupId>org.jfrog.test</groupId>
<artifactId>multi</artifactId>
<version>3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

and the artifacts getting deployed with repository-path "/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.7-SNAPSHOT/multi1-3.7-20210805.113313-6-sources.jar". Please find the below screenshot for your reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzTmJ.png)

You may use the maven example described in our Github page [here](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/maven-examples/maven-example)

And you can refer to the Youtube video link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVxhLIfunmI) in order to integrate the Artifactory application with Jenkins.

Comment: Hi pavan, thanks for your response. 

we already did all these configurations. Issue is am expecting the guidance on the groovy command in pipeline inorder to upload artifacts to jfrog.

Exact issue is am using free style job, so the direct artifactory plugin is not present in post build action. the available plugin in post build actions under free style job is for uploading one or two artifacts by mentioning the group and artifact id.

Comment: so I thought of enabling the groovy script in post build actions to upload all the artifacts to jfrog which are getting build.

If you can suggest any simpler way to accomplish this, am glad to give it a try.